# htaccess rewrite get just filename

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Basically I'm trying to rewrite by getting the filename only from certain directories (SEF format so no .php or .html) and then rewriting them.

For example, I want to change all the following (and other similar) directories

```
index.php/dir1/dir2/filename
index.php/dir1/filename
index.php/dir1/dir4/dir5/filename
```

And get back just

```
index.php/filename
```

Obviously the filename is different in every case and there are a lot of different directory combinations so I'd prefer a wildcard so ALL directories beginning with dir1 would be removed.

I'm pretty new to htaccess and although I can write a rule for each different directory structure there are so many it's getting crowded in my htaccess file. Surely there's a wildcard I can use which will simply remove all directory structures begining with dir1 and leave the filename?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(index\.php)/dir1.*?/([^\s/?]+)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1/%2 [L,R=302]
```

Comment: Thanks for that, but it still doesn't appear to work; it takes out DIR1 but still leaves in anything following (i.e. it doesn't remove the other directories before the filename). It would thus give: index.php/dir2/filename for the first example.

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't make any changes at all. The full URL is unchanged.

Comment: oh I had made a mistake, fixed it now. Can you try it.

Comment: Fantastic, anubhava - I just had to tweak it slightly

    RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(index\.php)/DIR1/.*?/([^\s/?]+)\s [NC]

And now it works fine. Thanks so much for your help! :)

Comment: Yes that is even better since it targets dir1 only. (My answer updated)